# Como ordenar uma lista de objetos através de um critério personalizado(sem order by)?

Tags: c#

eu peço a ajuda de vocês para resolver um problema que tem me aborrecido.
Eu tenho uma lista de escalas e gostaria de classificar ela através do Status(que por sua vez é uma propriedade da entidade HorarioEscala, mas o critério não é ordem alfabética, seria assim, as escalas com status "Aguardando Atendimento" ficariam no topo da listagem, seguidas pelas de status "Em atendimento", e por fim, as escalas com "Atendimento encerrado", eu já pensei na possibilidade de transformar esse Status de string para Enum para poder usar a função OrderBy, porém já existem muitos registros no banco de dados e então não daria certo, enfim, preciso de ajuda com a lógica para resolver esse problema, segue uma parte do código

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<EscalaViewModel>> ObterPorContratadaId(string contratadaId)
    {
        var escalas = await _escalaRepository.ObterPorContratadaId(contratadaId);
        var escalaView = new List<EscalaViewModel>();
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");

        if (escalas != null)
        {
            foreach (var escala in escalas)
            {
                var dataEscala = new List<DataEscalaViewModel>();
                foreach (var itemData in escala.DataEscalas.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.DataEntrada, cultureInfo)))
                {
                    if (itemData.DataEntrada == DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                    {
                        var horarioEscala = new List<HorarioEscalaViewModel>();
                        foreach (var horario in itemData.Horarios)
                        {
                            var entrada = new EntradaViewModel();
                            if (horario.Entrada != null)
                            {
                                entrada = new EntradaViewModel
                                {
                                    DataCheckIn = horario.Entrada.DataCheckIn,
                                    HoraCheckIn = horario.Entrada.HoraCheckIn,
                                    LatitudeCheckIn = horario.Entrada.LatitudeCheckIn,
                                    LongitudeCheckIn = horario.Entrada.LongitudeCheckIn
                                };
                            }

                            var saida = new SaidaViewModel();
                            if (horario.Saida != null)
                            {
                                saida = new SaidaViewModel
                                {
                                    DataCheckOut = horario.Saida.DataCheckOut,
                                    HoraCheckOut = horario.Saida.HoraCheckOut,
                                    LatitudeCheckOut = horario.Saida.LatitudeCheckOut,
                                    LongitudeCheckOut = horario.Saida.LongitudeCheckOut
                                };
                            }
                            horarioEscala.Add(new HorarioEscalaViewModel
                            {
                                Id = horario.Id,
                                TipoEscala = horario.TipoEscala,
                                MotivoDaEscala = horario.MotivoDaEscala,
                                HorarioInicio = horario.HorarioInicio,
                                HorarioFim = horario.HorarioFim,
                                Entrada = entrada,
                                Saida = saida,
                                TipoProfissional = horario.TipoProfissional,
                                ProfissionalId = horario.ProfissionalId,
                                ProfissionalUsuarioId = horario.ProfissionalUsuarioId,
                                PrestadorServicoId = horario.PrestadorServicoId,
                                NomePrestadorServico = horario.NomePrestadorServico,
                                NomeProfissional = horario.NomeProfissional,
                                AtividadeContratada = horario.AtividadeContratada,
                                Funcao = horario.Funcao,
                                Local = horario.Local,
                                Valor = horario.Valor,
                                Status = horario.Status,
                                CargoProfissional = horario.CargoProfissional,
                                RelatorioGerado = horario.RelatorioGerado
                            });


                            dataEscala.Add(new DataEscalaViewModel
                            {
                                Id = itemData.Id,
                                DataEntrada = itemData.DataEntrada,
                                DataSaida = itemData.DataSaida,
                                Horarios = horarioEscala
                            });

                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                if (dataEscala.Count() > 0)
                    escalaView.Add(new EscalaViewModel
                    {
                        Id = escala.Id,
                        HomeCareId = escala.HomeCareId,
                        PacienteId = escala.PacienteId,
                        DataEscalas = dataEscala

                    });

            }
        }

        return escalaView;
    }
```

Comment: Deu certo a resposta?

Comment: Olá, agradeço muito pela sua ajuda porque serviu como base para resolver, eu fui vasculhando e percebi que a solução viria do front, utilizei a função compare e atribui valores sequenciais(como no exemplo que vc deu) para cada status, com isso eu finalmente consegui ordenar, muuuuuuito obrigado mesmo, melhorou a minha forma de pensar

Comment: Então se for util assinale como resposta da sua pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria uma junção entre os três tipos com o método [Concat](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netcore-3.1) do [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) filtrando os parâmetros em sequencia, exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
class Item {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Status {get;set;}
}
class Items: List<Item> 
{
    public Items() 
    {
        Add(new Item { Id = 1, Status = "Aguardando Atendimento" });
        Add(new Item { Id = 2, Status = "Atendimento encerrado" });
        Add(new Item { Id = 3, Status = "Em atendimento" });
        Add(new Item { Id = 4, Status = "Atendimento encerrado" });
        Add(new Item { Id = 5, Status = "Aguardando Atendimento" });
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        //"Aguardando Atendimento"
        //"Em atendimento"
        //"Atendimento encerrado"
        Items items = new Items();
        var ordenado = items.Where(x => x.Status == "Aguardando Atendimento")
                .Concat(items.Where(x => x.Status == "Em atendimento"))
                .Concat(items.Where(x => x.Status == "Atendimento encerrado"));
                
        foreach(var c in ordenado)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", c.Id, c.Status);
        }
    }
}
```

[Exemplo Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6p1c7b)

---

Um outra forma é criando uma classe que vai comparar esses valores com a implementação da `interface` [IComparer<>](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer?view=netcore-3.1), e utilizar assim o [OrderBy](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1) com mais o segundo parâmetro: `OrderBy(x => x.Status, new StatusComparer())`, exemplo completo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
class Item {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Status {get;set;}
}
class Items: List<Item> 
{
    public Items() 
    {
        Add(new Item { Id = 1, Status = "Aguardando Atendimento" });
        Add(new Item { Id = 2, Status = "Atendimento encerrado" });
        Add(new Item { Id = 3, Status = "Em atendimento" });
        Add(new Item { Id = 4, Status = "Atendimento encerrado" });
        Add(new Item { Id = 5, Status = "Aguardando Atendimento" });
    }
}
class StatusComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> Filters = 
        new Dictionary<string, string>(3);
    public StatusComparer()
    {
        Filters.Add("Aguardando Atendimento", "a");
        Filters.Add("Em atendimento", "b");
        Filters.Add("Atendimento encerrado", "c");
    }
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        string aX = Filters[x];
        string yX = Filters[y];
        return aX.CompareTo(yX);
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        //"Aguardando Atendimento"
        //"Em atendimento"
        //"Atendimento encerrado"
        Items items = new Items();
        var ordenado = items.OrderBy(x => x.Status, new StatusComparer());
        foreach(var c in ordenado)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", c.Id, c.Status);
        }
    }
}
```

[Exemplo Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eiw9CM)